# Rebin data and update imshow plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, draw, imshow

I have a large data set I want to be able to "zoom" in on.

What I really want is for the data to be rebinned based on the selection and then update the data in the graph. So the graph will show different limits but maintain the same resolution. Currently the imshow isn't getting updated. There must be something I'm missing or don't understand any insight would be appreciated.

Random data working example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

class Annotate(object):
  def __init__(self,x,y):
      self.ax = plt.gca()
      self.x = x
      self.y = y
      self.rect = Rectangle((0,0), 0, 0, facecolor='None', edgecolor='red')
      self.im = plt.imshow(np.zeros((150,150)))
      self.x0 = None
      self.y0 = None
      self.x1 = None
      self.y1 = None
      self.ax.add_patch(self.rect)
      self.ax.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.on_press)
      self.ax.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_release_event', self.on_release)
      self.ax.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', self.on_motion)
  def on_press(self, event):
      print ('press')
      self.is_pressed = True
      self.x0 = event.xdata
      self.y0 = event.ydata    
      self.x1 = event.xdata
      self.y1 = event.ydata
      self.rect.set_width(self.x1 - self.x0)
      self.rect.set_height(self.y1 - self.y0)
      self.rect.set_xy((self.x0, self.y0))
      #self.rect.set_linestyle('dashed')
      self.ax.figure.canvas.draw()
  def on_motion(self,event):
      if self.on_press is True:
          return
      self.x1 = event.xdata
      self.y1 = event.ydata
      self.rect.set_width(self.x1 - self.x0)
      self.rect.set_height(self.y1 - self.y0)
      self.rect.set_xy((self.x0, self.y0))
      #self.rect.set_linestyle('dashed')
      if self.is_pressed == True:
          self.ax.figure.canvas.draw()
  def on_release(self, event):
      print ('release')
      self.is_pressed= False
      self.x1 = event.xdata
      self.y1 = event.ydata
      self.rect.set_width(self.x1 - self.x0)
      self.rect.set_height(self.y1 - self.y0)
      self.rect.set_xy((self.x0, self.y0))
      self.rect.set_linestyle('solid')
      update_data(self)
      #self.ax.set_ylim( min(self.y0, self.y1), max(self.y0, self.y1))
      #self.ax.set_xlim( min(self.x0, self.x1), max(self.x0, self.x1))
      self.ax.figure.canvas.draw()
      print (self.x0,self.x1,self.y0,self.y1)
      return [self.x0,self.x1,self.y0,self.y1]


#x = np.random.randint(0,500, size=10000)
x= np.arange(10000)
y = np.random.randint(0,500, size=10000)

Z, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x,y, bins=150)

def update_data(selection):
    ymin= min(selection.y0, selection.y1)
    ymax= max(selection.y0, selection.y1)
    xmin= min(selection.x0, selection.x1)
    xmax= max(selection.x0, selection.x1)
    low_index = np.argmax(selection.x>xmin)
    high_index = np.argmax(selection.y>xmax)
    Z, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x[low_index:high_index],y, bins=150)
    selection.im.set_data(Z)
    selection.im.set_extent([xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax])
    plt.draw()

selection = Annotate(x,y)

selection.im=plt.imshow(Z, interpolation='none', extent=[0,500,0,500])
plt.colorbar()

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing the limits on the `y` value in the histogram redraw in `update_data`. The high index and low index are also the wrong way around. The following looks more promising,

```
    Z, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x[high_index:low_index],y[high_index:low_index], bins=150)
```

(although I'm not sure it's exactly what you want)

EDIT: The following appears to zoom and redraw.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

class Annotate(object):
  def __init__(self,x,y):
      self.figure = plt.gcf()
      self.ax = plt.gca()
      self.x = x
      self.y = y
      self.rect = Rectangle((0,0), 0, 0, facecolor='None', edgecolor='red')
      self.im = plt.imshow(np.zeros((150,150)))
      self.x0 = None
      self.y0 = None
      self.x1 = None
      self.y1 = None
      self.is_pressed = False
      self.ax.add_patch(self.rect)
      self.ax.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.on_press)
      self.ax.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_release_event', self.on_release)
      self.ax.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', self.on_motion)
  def on_press(self, event):
      print ('press')
      self.is_pressed = True
      self.x0 = event.xdata
      self.y0 = event.ydata    
      self.x1 = event.xdata
      self.y1 = event.ydata
      self.rect.set_width(self.x1 - self.x0)
      self.rect.set_height(self.y1 - self.y0)
      self.rect.set_xy((self.x0, self.y0))
      #self.rect.set_linestyle('dashed')
      self.ax.figure.canvas.draw()
  def on_motion(self,event):
      if self.is_pressed is False:
          return
      self.x1 = event.xdata
      self.y1 = event.ydata
      #if type(self.x1) is float and type(self.y1) is float:
      self.rect.set_width(self.x1 - self.x0)
      self.rect.set_height(self.y1 - self.y0)
      self.rect.set_xy((self.x0, self.y0))
      #self.rect.set_linestyle('dashed')
      if self.is_pressed == True:
          self.ax.figure.canvas.draw()
  def on_release(self, event):
      print ('release')
      self.is_pressed= False
      self.x1 = event.xdata
      self.y1 = event.ydata
      self.rect.set_width(self.x1 - self.x0)
      self.rect.set_height(self.y1 - self.y0)
      self.rect.set_xy((self.x0, self.y0))
      self.rect.set_linestyle('solid')
      update_data(self)
      #self.ax.set_ylim( min(self.y0, self.y1), max(self.y0, self.y1))
      #self.ax.set_xlim( min(self.x0, self.x1), max(self.x0, self.x1))
      self.ax.figure.canvas.draw()

      print (self.x0,self.x1,self.y0,self.y1)
      return [self.x0,self.x1,self.y0,self.y1]


#x = np.random.randint(0,500, size=10000)
x = np.arange(5000)
y = np.random.randint(0,500, size=5000)

Z, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=150, normed=True)

def update_data(selection):
    ymin= min(selection.y0, selection.y1)
    ymax= max(selection.y0, selection.y1)
    xmin= min(selection.x0, selection.x1)
    xmax= max(selection.x0, selection.x1)
    low_index = np.argmax(selection.x>xmin)
    high_index = np.argmax(selection.y>xmax)
    Z, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x[high_index:low_index],y[high_index:low_index], bins=150, normed=True)

    selection.ax.figure.clf(keep_observers=True)
    selection.ax = selection.ax.figure.add_subplot(111)
    selection.im=plt.imshow(Z, interpolation='none', extent=[xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])
    plt.colorbar(selection.im)


selection = Annotate(x,y)

selection.im=plt.imshow(Z, interpolation='none', extent=[y.min(), y.max(), y.min(), y.max()])
plt.colorbar(selection.im)

plt.show()
```

Comment: In this example the y data is random while the x data is linear. Just for the example I was trying to keep it as simple as possible to focus on the issue of the image not being refreshed.
I think the index should go from low to high though python is smart enough to interpret high to low as decrementing.

Comment: I edited the question to hopefully provide some clarity on what i'm asking.

Comment: May be difference in version of matplotlib but the indices threw an error for me. I had a similar problem with redrawing on pcolormesh (i.e. it didn't redraw). The solution was to use `selection.ax.figure.clf(keep_observers=True)` to clear the figure, re-add the axis `selection.ax = selection.ax.figure.add_subplot(111)`, call pcolormesh with the new data and finally `selection.ax.figure.canvas.draw()` to update...

Comment: Its a step in the right direction! Seems to reduce the data to either one or zero but it is redrawing the figure. Although the rectangle no longer is displayed. I'll leave this active for a while in the hopes that a solution is found. In my mind the graph should look the same after zooming but the axis should change. 
Thank you for taking the time to help me. I will select your answer if no other solution is found.

Comment: This led me to a solution. Thank you for helping me to solve this problem. It only works once disabling the rectangle selection I'll tackle that next.

What worked for me:
    Z, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x[low_index:high_index],y[low_index:high_index], bins=150)